How can I hide the Mac taskbar when using VMware in fullscreen?
I have a Mac mini M2 (Mac OS v. 15) and I'm running Windows 11 on it in a VM using Vmware Fusion.
When the VM is displayed in Fullscreen and I move the mouse to the side where the Mac taskbar is, the taskbar pops up, in front of the VM.
How can I prevent this behavior?

Right-clicking the bar and selecting "Turn Hiding On" should make it go away.
If you're asking about the menu bar, then putting the app in the full screen should make it go away.
